# Bounding the derivative of a $C^2$ functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Assume $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is $C^2$ and $|f''(x)|\leq A$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that the inequality $$f'(x)^2\leq 2Af(x)$$

The hint is to use Taylor's theorem

I havent got far using Talyor expansion $f(x+t)=f(x)+f'(x)t+f''(\xi)t^2/2$
Any other ideas and hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Since the function is non-negative, the left side (and hence the right side) is non-negative. With the bound on the second derivative,
$$0 \leq f(x+t) = f(x) + f'(x) t + \frac{f''(\zeta)}{2}t^2 \leq f(x) + f'(x) t + \frac{A}{2}t^2.$$
The right side is quadratic in $t$, so the discriminant is less than or equal to 0. That is,
$$f'(x)^2 - 2Af(x) \leq 0 \qquad{} \Rightarrow \qquad{} f'(x)^2 \leq 2Af(x).$$
The $C^2$ condition can be relaxed -- Taylor's Theorem only requires that the first derivative is continuous on $[x,x+t]$ and that the second derivative exists on $(x,x+t)$.